# Server 2012 network share cannot be accessed on Windows 10 through cisco vpn

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10

We have a user who is at home trying to get access to our Windows 2012 server network share. He can view network shares on 2008 but not on 2012.

We had this previous problem with users on Windows 8.1 when not on the LAN, but when they vpn they couldn't see the share. There is a fix on Windows 8.1 to run this power shell command

Set-ItemProperty -Path “HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters” RequireSecureNegotiate -Value 0 -Force

But that doesn't work in Windows 10. Is there a similar fix for Windows 10?